# Shapefile layer not showing in Windows/QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to load a US county shapefile in QGIS (for Windows). It appears to load OK and a new layer appears in the project, but I cannot see the shapefile outlines. When I do the same thing with the same file on Mac, it works just fine. Any thoughts?

I am on QGIS 3.4.14(Madeira) on Mac and 3.14.1(Pi) on Windows. Link to shapefile:

https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_county_500k.zip

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or two to show the problem?

Comment: Do you see the attributes in the attribute table? Have you tried to change the rendering styles from Properties - Symbology?

Comment: And have you made sure the little check box "render" in the right hand bottom corner is checked ? Otherwise it wouldn't show the geometries

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain exactly how you load the shapefile.